# I can't repel (filter) the lower case First name while using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

nice predecessors in stack overflow, I kept trying to write a regular expression that can output the names who has their random first name and Nakamoto as their family name.

Like these:

```
Yoshida Nakamoto
Yukari Nakamoto
Hey Nakamoto
```

Not these:

```
yoshida Nakamoto
Nakamoto
Y2D Nakamoto
```

The thing is, I tried and filed to filter out those who use lowercase first names.

I've tried:

```
[A-Z]+
[^A-Z]
[^A-Z]{1}
```

but failed all the times, the output differs but nothing was as I expected.

```
#! python3
# nameRex.py
# this is a regular expression to find out those have Nakamoto as family name.


import pprint, re

matches = []

nameList = ['Saoshi Nakamoto',
            'Alice Nakamoto',
            'RoboCop Nakamoto',
            'satoshi Nakamoto',
            'Mr. Nakamoto',
            'Nakamoto',
            'Satoshi nakamoto',
            'Y2D Nakamoto']

nakamotoOrNot = re.compile(r'''
    [^A-Z]{1}
    (\w+)
    (\s)?
    (Nakamoto)
    ''',  re.VERBOSE)

for groups in nakamotoOrNot.findall(str(nameList)):
    matches.append(groups)

pprint.pprint(matches)
```

As above, the expected results are:

```
[('Saoshi', ' ', 'Nakamoto'),
 ('Alice', ' ', 'Nakamoto'),
 ('RoboCop', ' ', 'Nakamoto')]
```

But the actual results are:

```
[('Saoshi', ' ', 'Nakamoto'),
 ('Alice', ' ', 'Nakamoto'),
 ('RoboCop', ' ', 'Nakamoto'),
 ('satoshi', ' ', 'Nakamoto')] # This thing just won't go away!!!!
```

Help!!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please state clearly what characteristics the strings that match and do not match your intended regex should have.

Comment: `[^A-Z]{1}` THIS.........says do "not" start with a single capital letter. You seem to mean to say `^[A-Z]{1}` which is starts with.    Additionally `(\s)?` means 0 or 1 spaces. It's better to use `[\ ]*` in this case. Thirdly, if that's your regex you realize that all of the spaces before the `^[A-Z]{1}` will get processed as the entire expression, right?

Comment: @FailSafe Thanks for you comment! And yes, I meant to say it starts with an uppercase letter. And no, I did not know that the spaces in front of that first line would be counted as well. Thanks so much for telling me these!

Comment: BTW, `(\w+)` means you're independently capturing that group and in terms of your regex, you don't want that because it will ignore the preceding Capital letters in this context. Honestly, I'm thinking of posting an explanation so you understand it better. At this rate, you will run into a lot of problems with regex.
Do you need me to post an explanation?

Comment: @FailSafe Thank you for your hearty help, and at this point I think that I should study the regex video tutorial several times more, and try out more. Your explanation would be fantastic, I believe, but will cost you too much of time. Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm on this. I will be expecting your answer next time, though.

Comment: No prob. If you're following sentdex's tutorial, don't. I haven't watched the others, but  I saw his a while back and man was it *not good*

Comment: @FailSafe Thanks for the advice, I bought some course on the udemy and it works fine, at least it seems to be.

Comment: Ok. Cool. Was it Zero to HEro with Python or was it focused on regex?

Comment: @FailSafe Thanks, it was called Automate the Boring stuff with Python, I now found it too coarse to continue on as I started to encounter a lot of problems even that I was barely copying the code from the book, so I switched to Learn Python the hard way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, key pointers are here:

1. fullmatch the string
2. start with uppercase
3. only contains alphabet in first name
4. last name is Nakamoto

by the way, I suggest you compare the string in list one by one, not convert list to str, it costs more to build a new string, and difficult to use fullmatch.

```
matches = []

nameList = ['Saoshi Nakamoto',
            'Alice Nakamoto',
            'RoboCop Nakamoto',
            'satoshi Nakamoto',
            'Mr. Nakamoto',
            'Nakamoto',
            'Satoshi nakamoto',
            'Y2D Nakamoto']

nakamotoOrNot = re.compile('[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+ Nakamoto')

for name in nameList:
    if nakamotoOrNot.fullmatch(name):
        matches.append(name)

print(matches)
```

output:
`['Saoshi Nakamoto', 'Alice Nakamoto', 'RoboCop Nakamoto']`

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )